# Queries regarding UPDATE in SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This is my TABLE DESC:

```
Customer (Custid, Custname, Addr, phno,panno) 
Loan (Loanid, Amount, Interest, Custid)
Account (Accid, Accbal, Custid)
```

Now I need to update the table "loan" for the specified Condition

QUERY IS :

```
Update the interest with 1% when Accbal >50% of Loan Amount
```

I barely needed a SINGLE LINE QUERY (SQL PLUS). Is a single line query possible for this updation or should I go for creating a procedure for updation. A single line query is most welcomed.

Comment: `Update the interest with 1%` , you want to increase interest by 1% or set it to 1%?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way

```
update Loan 
Set Interest = Interest + (1 * Interest )/100 
where Custid IN (select Custid from Account where Accbal > 50);
```

**EDIT**

```
update Loan 
Set Interest = Interest + (1 * Interest )/100 
where Custid IN (
    select a.Custid 
     from Account left outer join Loan 
       on Account.Custid = Loan.Custid 
        where Account.Accbal > (Loan.amount)/ 2
);
```

Comment: i.e, "accbal>0.5*amount"

Comment: hmmm...wont u be able to merge `where` clause now...?? :)

Comment: try doing it....looks gud to me for a trial, if it doesnt work, check the edit i just added!

Comment: update loan set interest=interest+(0.01*Interest) where custid in(select ac
    count.custid from loan,account where account.accbal>0.5*loan.amount);